# Extract XML to json via bash

Tags: json, xml, bash, sed

I am trying to find some specific information in an XML tag and convert it to a json string. I have come up with the most convoluted solution, but it almost works. I just need to remove the whitespace and line breaks. I have tried however that results in even my values to run together.

Sample data:

```
<config>
  <derivedFrom>
    <courseName>Family and Medical Leave</courseName>
    <courseCode>FML</courseCode>
    <courseAuthor>Company 1</courseAuthor>
    <courseVersion>2.0.0</courseVersion>
    <importLocale>en-US</importLocale>
  </derivedFrom>
</config>
```

This is the sed code I am using:

```
sed -n '
    /<derivedFrom>/ {
    :a;
    N;
    /<\/derivedFrom>/!ba;
    s/.*<derivedFrom>//;
    s/<\/derivedFrom>//;
    s/<\/[a-zA-Z]*>/",/g;
    s/</"/g;
    s/>/":"/g;
    s/[[:space:]]//g;
    s/,$//g;
    p
    }'
```

And finally, here is my current output is `"courseName":"FamilyandMedicalLeave","courseCode":"UBM2C","courseAuthor":"Alchemy","courseVersion":"2.0.021","importLocale":"en-US"`

I know I need to replace `[[:space:]]` with something else as I don't want text in my quotes to run together, but I am stuck. For example: Family and Medical Leave should keep its spaces. There is probably also an easier way to do this with some XML to JSON script. However, I need to do this without needing to install anything else onto the servers.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel when you can use the ones existing already https://github.com/hay/xml2json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I don't know all the details about xml and json. As you specify you cannot install a program, here's some steps using `sed` and `paste` that might help you. This is intended as guide and may not be full answer you are expecting, and assumes data format as shown in sample

**Step 1**: getting required lines (See [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38978201) for details)

```
$ sed -n '/<derivedFrom>/, /<\/derivedFrom>/{//!p}' ip.txt
    <courseName>Family and Medical Leave</courseName>
    <courseCode>FML</courseCode>
    <courseAuthor>Company 1</courseAuthor>
    <courseVersion>2.0.0</courseVersion>
    <importLocale>en-US</importLocale>
```

**Step 2**: Re-format the filtered lines
Can also combine with previous step as `//!s|.*<\([^>]*\)>\(.*\)</\1>.*|"\1":"\2"|p`

```
sed 's|.*<\([^>]*\)>\(.*\)</\1>.*|"\1":"\2"|'
"courseName":"Family and Medical Leave"
"courseCode":"FML"
"courseAuthor":"Company 1"
"courseVersion":"2.0.0"
"importLocale":"en-US"
```

**Step 3**: join them using paste

```
paste -sd,
"courseName":"Family and Medical Leave","courseCode":"FML","courseAuthor":"Company 1","courseVersion":"2.0.0","importLocale":"en-US"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is much cleaner and nicer than what I was using. I, unfortunately, couldn't get `paste` to work, but I was able to use another sed to remove the line breaks and replace them with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply ? Valid for Bash

```
sed -n '
    /<derivedFrom>/ {
    :a;
    N;
    /<\/derivedFrom>/!ba;
    s/.*<derivedFrom>//;
    s/<\/derivedFrom>//;
    s/<\/[a-zA-Z]*>/",/g;
    s/</"/g;
    s/>/":"/g;
    s/,$//g;
    p
    }' input.txt | sed 's/^ *//g;s/ *$//g'
```

Regards!